# Бот не проигрывает музыку через вконтакте, хотя подключается

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, discord.py

````
from vk_api.audio import VkAudio
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Status
import random
import asyncio
from discord.utils import get
from yt_dlp import YoutubeDL

vk_session = VkApi(token='мой токен вк')
vk = vk_session.get_api()
config = {
    'token': 'токен бота дс',
    'prefix': '$',
}

intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config['prefix'], intents=intents)

bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    statuses = ['Ну а что поделать?', 'Да да я...', '/help', 'Че смотришь?']
    while True:
        await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.dnd)
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=random.choice(statuses)))
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

# @bot.command()
# async def play(ctx, url, description='Заказ музыки / Временно не работает'):
#     """
#     Проигрывает музыку с YouTube в голосовом канале автора команды.
#     Использование: /play [URL YouTube видео]
#     """
#     if ctx.author.voice:
#         voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel  

#         voice_client = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
#         if voice_client and voice_client.is_connected():
#             await voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
#         else:
#             voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()

#         ydl_opts = {'format': 'bestaudio'}
#         with YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
#             info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)

#         url2 = info['formats'][0]['url'] 

#         voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(url2, before_options='-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5'))
#         await ctx.send(f'Воспроизвожу музыку: {info["title"]}')
#     else:
#         await ctx.send('Вы должны быть в голосовом канале, чтобы использовать эту команду.')

# @bot.command()
# async def stop(ctx):
#     voice_client = ctx.voice_client

#     if voice_client:
#         await voice_client.disconnect()
#         await ctx.send('Бот покинул голосовой канал.')
#     else:
#         await ctx.send('Бот не находится в голосовом канале.')

@bot.command(description='Тестовая команда')
async def command(ctx):
    """
    Тестовая команда
    """
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send('Я робот')

blocked_words = ['пидор', 'пидорасина', 'негр', 'негритосик', 'хохол', 'русня']  # Список запрещенных слов

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    for word in blocked_words:
        if word in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()  # Удаление сообщения-нарушителя
            await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.mention}, не пиши такие плохие слова. :smiling_face_with_tear:')  # Отправка сообщения с упоминанием нарушителя
            break 
    await bot.process_commands(message)  # Обработка других команд

@bot.command()
async def furry(ctx,description='Узнай насколько ты фурри'):
    """
    Показывает на сколько ты фурри.
    Использование: /furry
    """
    percentage = random.randint(0, 100)  # Генерация случайного числа от 0 до 100
    if percentage < 20:
        await ctx.send(f"Ты фурри на {percentage}%, так держать!")
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Ты фурри на {percentage}%, фу мерзость!")

@bot.command()
async def help(ctx, description='Список всех комманд'):
    """Все команды бота.
    Использование: /help
    """
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Всевозможные команды", description="Список доступных команд бота:", color=discord.Color.blue())
    
    for command in bot.commands:
        embed.add_field(name=command.name, value=command.help, inline=False)
    
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
@commands.has_any_role('Амикус', 'Пуфыстый модератор')  # проверка на наличие ролей администратора или модератора
async def clear(ctx, amount: int, description='Удаление сообщений'):
    """
    Удаляет указанное количество сообщений из текущего канала чата.
    Использование: /clear [количество]
    """
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
    await ctx.send(f'Удалено {amount} сообщений.')

@bot.command()
async def users(ctx, description='Кол-во участников сервера'):
    """
    Показывает кол-во людей и ботов на этом дискорд сервере.
    Использование: /users
    """
    member_count = len(ctx.guild.members)
    await ctx.send(f"На этом сервере сейчас {member_count} участника(ов).")

# @bot.command() #рандомные реакции
# async def random_reactions(ctx):
#     messages = await ctx.channel.history(limit=None).flatten()  # получение всех сообщений в текущем канале
#     random_messages = random.choices(messages, k=int(len(messages) * 0.9)) 

#     for message in random_messages:
#         reactions = [':white_check_mark:', ':rainbow:', ':heart:', ':saluting_face:', ':skull_crossbones:']  # список рандомных реакций
#         reaction = random.choice(reactions)  # выбор рандомной реакции
#         await message.add_reaction(reaction)  # добавление реакции к сообщению

@bot.event #рандомные реакции
async def on_message(message):
    if random.random() < 0.2:  
        emoji = random.choice(bot.emojis)
        try:
            await message.add_reaction(emoji)
        except discord.errors.HTTPException:
            pass
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, query):
    """
    Проигрывает музыку с Вконтакте в голосовом канале автора команды.
    Использование: /play [название трека или исполнителя]
    """
    if ctx.author.voice:
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel  

        voice_client = get(bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        if voice_client and voice_client.is_connected():
            await voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
        else:
            voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()

        vkaudio = VkAudio(vk)
        try:
            tracks = vkaudio.search(query)

            if tracks:
                track = tracks[0]  # Получение первого трека из результатов поиска
                url = track['url']  # Получение URL трека

                response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
                
                if response.status_code == 200:
                    filename = f'{track["artist"]} - {track["title"]}.mp3'  # Формирование имени файла из исполнителя и названия трека
                    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
                        f.write(response.content)

                    voice_client.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename))
                    await ctx.send(f'Воспроизвожу музыку: {track["artist"]} - {track["title"]}')
                else:
                    await ctx.send('Не удалось получить трек.')
            else:
                await ctx.send('Трек не найден.')
        except KeyError:
            await ctx.send('Произошла ошибка при поиске трека.')
    else:
        await ctx.send('Вы должны быть в голосовом канале, чтобы использовать эту команду.')

bot.run(config['token'])```


**Ошибки**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\comp\Desktop\bot discrod\bot.py", line 167, in play
    vkaudio = VkAudio(vk)
  File "C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\vk_api\audio.py", line 81, in __init__
    self.user_id = vk.method('users.get')[0]['id']
TypeError: VkApiMethod.__call__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: VkApiMethod.__call__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were givenTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 235, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\comp\Desktop\bot discrod\bot.py", line 167, in play
    vkaudio = VkAudio(vk)
  File "C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\vk_api\audio.py", line 81, in __init__
    self.user_id = vk.method('users.get')[0]['id']
TypeError: VkApiMethod.__call__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1029, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\comp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 244, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: VkApiMethod.__call__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
````